# ESP-NOW: Master and Slave at the same time

Tags: wifi, esp32

I am interested to use ESP-NOW as a means to transmit data between two ESP32's back and forth, - each ESP receives and sends data, taking turns. The example library provides an example sketch for Slave and one for Master, which allows for one-directional data flow. However, I would like to use ESP-NOW for two-way communication. Is it possible to combine both of these sketches to allow the data to flow in both directions at the same time?

[image: ESP32 Library showing Slave and Master examples]

I'm assuming two ESP's won't be able to send data at the same exact time, so the best approach to start, I think, would be to wait until a packet has been received before sending one from the other end. Here's a snippet of code which I tried to use, but failed:

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_MODE_APSTA);
  // configure device AP mode
  configDeviceAP();
  // This is the mac address of the Slave in AP Mode
  Serial.print("AP MAC: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.softAPmacAddress());
  Serial.print("STA MAC: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.macAddress());
  // Init ESPNow with a fallback logic
  InitESPNow();
  // Once ESPNow is successfully Init, we will register for recv CB to
  // get recv packer info.
  esp_now_register_recv_cb(OnDataRecv);
  esp_now_register_send_cb(OnDataSent);
}

unsigned long nextManage;

void loop() 
{
  // In the loop we scan for slave
  ScanForSlave();
  // If Slave is found, it would be populate in `slave` variable
  // We will check if `slave` is defined and then we proceed further
  if (slave.channel == CHANNEL2)
  { // check if slave channel is defined
    // `slave` is defined
    // Add slave as peer if it has not been added already
    bool isPaired = manageSlave();
    nextManage = millis() + 10000;
    while (isPaired)
    {
      if (packetRecieved)
      {
        packetRecieved = false;
        // Send data to device
        sendData();
      }

      unsigned long t = millis();
      if (t > nextManage)
      {
        nextManage = t + 10000;
        // pair success or already paired
        isPaired = manageSlave();
      }
    }
    Serial.println("Slave pair failed!");
  }
}
```

Comment: "ESPNow" is part of the ESP IDF. You can read more here: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/network/esp_now.html - it's not Arduino functionality, but something that is closed source and custom to ESP32.

Comment: @Majenko I see. Then the one I made on [espressif forum](https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=11752) would be more applicable I guess. I will keep this one up for a while just in case. Thanks